# App fails to lauch, logcat says line 29 which seems to be okay

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is the code, line 29 corresponds to the the bextras button config, and it seems right.
Line 29 - extras.setTypeface(font3); When I delete it and launch the app, it goes to the extras.setOnClickListener and display an error there, the app works fine when I remove the whole extra button and its props, including the setOnClickListener.

Whats wrong?

```
public class TheBeginning extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_beginning);
    Button gogym = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bgym);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Sanvito.ttf");
    gogym.setTypeface(font);
    Button gofav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bfav);
    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Sanvito.ttf");
    gofav.setTypeface(font1);
    Button goindex = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bindex);
    Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Sanvito.ttf");
    goindex.setTypeface(font2);
    Button extras = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bextra1);
    Typeface font3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Sanvito.ttf");
    **extras.setTypeface(font3);** //Line 29
    TextView minit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minititle);
    Typeface font4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Alba.TTF");
    minit.setTypeface(font4);

    gogym.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent gogymint = new     Intent("com.irespekt.gymbook.GOTOgym");
            startActivity(gogymint);
        }
    });
    gofav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent gofavint = new Intent("com.irespekt.gymbook.GOTOFAV");
            startActivity(gofavint);
        }
    });
    goindex.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent goindexint = new Intent(
                        "com.irespekt.gymbook.INDEXPAGEACTIVITY");
            startActivity(goindexint);
        }
    });
    extras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent extrasint = new Intent(
                    "com.irespekt.gymbook.PICTUREVIEWFLIP");
            startActivity(extrasint);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.the_beginning, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

EDIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.com.irespekt.gymbook"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.TheBeginning"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.GoToGym"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.GOTOGYM" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.GoToFav"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.GOTOFAV" />






            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.IndexPageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.INDEXPAGEACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.WebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.WEBVIEWACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.PictureViewFlip"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irespekt.gymbook.PICTUREVIEWFLIP" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LAYOUT XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="186dp"
    android:layout_weight="16.78"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bgym"
        style="@style/btnStylePaprika"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15.0dip"
        android:text="Go To Gym"
        android:textSize="20.0sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bfav"
        style="@style/btnStylePaprika"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:text="Favorites"
        android:textSize="20.0sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bindex"
        style="@style/btnStylePaprika"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:text="Index"
        android:textSize="20.0sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bextra1"
        style="@style/btnStylePaprika"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:text="Extras"
        android:textSize="20.0sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LOGCAT

```
11-28 12:35:42.598: D/dalvikvm(875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 6% free 2589K/2732K, paused 243ms, total 257ms
11-28 12:35:42.658: I/dalvikvm-heap(875): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.638MB for 2139636-byte allocation
11-28 12:35:42.761: D/dalvikvm(875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 4676K/4824K, paused 106ms, total 106ms
11-28 12:35:44.048: D/AndroidRuntime(875): Shutting down VM
11-28 12:35:44.048: W/dalvikvm(875): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.irespekt.gymbook/com.irespekt.gymbook.TheBeginning}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.irespekt.gymbook.TheBeginning.onCreate(TheBeginning.java:29)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-28 12:35:44.148: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  ... 11 more
11-28 12:36:09.321: I/Process(875): Sending signal. PID: 875 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you provide the full LogCat as well as the layout xml where bextra1 is defined?

Comment: @TheCapn Please check my edit, it contains all you will need, were you able to find anything?

Comment: Log cat showing you are getting a null pointer exception. Can you tell us on which line it is showing that ?

Comment: So intelligent you are i must say. Don't you know that line numbers are in eclipse. how can i possibly know here which is line 29? because you code starts with the class declaration and in eclipse line numbering starts with package declaration.

Comment: yes I know, thats why I'm telling you = Line 29 - extras.setTypeface(font3); as it is in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyBad... I'm sorry, I found the error.

The button with id - bextra, had an id of gonow, before, now I changed the id in the activity_thebeginning.xml layout, and FORGOT to rename the rest in the xlarge, xland etc, causing the error.

I'm sorry if I gave anyone headaches. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to keep your assets folder inside your project and not inside

src And then, create a folder called fonts inside assets. then, put the specific font typeface ttf files inside it.You can use the font typeface in coding like:

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Sanvito.ttf");
    gogym.setTypeface(font);

there is problem in  below statement

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Sanvito.ttf");
```

Comment: But all other buttons above this first worked well, as a matter of fact, the extras button along with the fonts were working well, I dont know what I did that disrupt the config, I knew the error started when I created a new activity the PictureFlipActivity, after adding to the manifest, and app was run, error occurs. Trouble